# Como redimensionar RelativeLayout enquanto o teclado está ativo

Tags: android, android-layout, teclado, redimensionamento

Boa noite! Sou iniciante no android, então me desculpem se é uma pergunta idiota. Não encontrei solução pro meu problema neste fórum, então, decidi criar esse post.
Tenho uma aplicação bem simples, como na imagem abaixo:
[image: Layout sem teclado]

Quando o usuário toca no EditText e o teclado aparece, toda a minha aplicação é empurrada para cima. Eu não quero que isso aconteça: Em vez disso, gostaria que o RelativeLayout se redimensionasse para caber na tela, como no desenho:
[image: Layout com teclado]

Qual é a melhor maneira de fazer isso? Obrigado!

Comment: Você pode tentar usar a tag android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" no manifest. Ele pode ser setado via activity também        getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

Comment: @franM Funcionou perfeitamente! Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A franM respondeu minha pergunta em comentário:

Você pode usar essa tag no manifest:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Ou pode ser setado via Activity também

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE‌​);
```